# Adding a auto incremental column into existing redshift table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift.

I want to add a column which should have incremental values. I dont want to drop the table and create a new one.

Please suggest the command to add a column having auto incremental values in redshift table.

Thanks !!!

Comment: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40212352/1265306) [ALTER TABLE APPEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html) works!

Answer (score 5):

Use CREATE TABLE to add a new table with identity column and then use [ALTER TABLE APPEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html) with FILLTARGET modifier, and then drop the original table and rename the new table it is extremely fast and simple.

> If the target table contains columns that don't exist in the source
>   table, include FILLTARGET. The command fills the extra columns in the
>   source table with either the default column value or IDENTITY value,
>   if one was defined, or NULL.

It moves the columns from one table to another, extremely fast, took me 4s for 1GB table in dc1.large node.

> Appends rows to a target table by moving data from an existing source
>   table.
>   ...
>   ALTER TABLE APPEND is usually much faster than a similar CREATE TABLE
>   AS or INSERT INTO operation because data is moved, not duplicated.

```
/* This is your table to be modified */
CREATE TABLE t_original (a varchar);
INSERT INTO t_original VALUES ('v1'), ('v2');

/* Here are the steps to add IDENTITY column */
CREATE TABLE t_new (id  BIGINT IDENTITY(0,1), a varchar);
ALTER TABLE t_new APPEND FROM t_original FILLTARGET;
DROP TABLE t_original;
ALTER TABLE t_new RENAME TO t_original;

/* Show the result */
SELECT * FROM t_original;
 id | a
----+----
  1 | v2
  0 | v1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: If you follow this and have issues with matching attributes, you can get your source table column attributes from svv_redshift_columns and alter the destination table so both table attributes match

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add an IDENTITY column to an existing table.

It might be easiest to create a new table with the new IDENTITY column, and copy the data into it.  Note that the values aren't guaranteed to increase monotonically - i.e. there may be gaps.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html :

> You cannot use an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN command to modify the following
> table and column attributes:
>
> UNIQUE
>
> PRIMARY KEY
>
> REFERENCES (foreign key)
>
> IDENTITY